# Can't install driver for RTL8188C

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu

I am currently running a dual-boot **Xubuntu** and windows 7. I have one wireless usb adapter which is non-branded. Though I was successfully able to install the given driver in the CD of the driver I cannot install it in the xubuntu.
I have the driver that was provided with the wireless driver in the link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o2QwkaKErzGZrzNmzmFaHg9FsmE0HrmD

If anyone is kind enough to instruct me how to install the driver please inform me. The name that was given in the folder of the driver was **RTL8188C_8192C** so I supposed it was the name of the driver since it did not have any name it its packet as I mentioned it is non-branded.
So if anyone knows how to install the driver or have a link for the driver please let me know.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that a circa-2012 driver suite will ever build on any recent Ubuntu version. Let's find a better way. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do it the following :

open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), (or preferably move to the folder with all the files you shared (install.sh, ect...) and right click on empty space and select the menu option "open in terminal"), if you simply opened up a terminal and are in the wrong folder you can put yourself in that directory in the terminal by typing `cd Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105` (or whatever the real path to the folder is, `cd` means "Change directory"), then in the opened termianl window, type :

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

(if you wish to copy paste these commands in there are several methods, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> them here then in the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or you can simply highlight them here, then in the terminal press down the scroll wheel)

then once you've done that we are certain your install script is executable (it very likely already was).

then you may execute it with :

```
./install.sh
```

it might prompt you for details as to your prefered instalations settings or it may be able to sort everything out on it's own.

`.sh` is a file extention for shell scripts a universal (universal as in, it `.sh` is runnable on every operating system) executable file type that cannot contain much beyond scripting. Scripts however are very usefull for both installing things and automating repeatable tasks.

this isn't the last time you'll use `.sh` files. Many linux programs use them as launchers or installers.

hope this helped! :)

Comment: sorry for that and thanks for the help. I somewhat thought you were going to do something. thanks again and I hope this works

Comment: by the way you don't have to type whole commands. just type the three first letters of a word or a folder name or file and then hit the "TAB" key on your keyboard, it will autocomplete. this is much faster.

Comment: sorry but there isnt any install file or anything with the name install and when I gave the command you gave I got output :    chmod: connot access 'install.sh' : No such file or directory         bash: ./install.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: well that's a pretty understandable mesage wouldn't you say? you're in the wrong folder aren't you? look at the line at the begining of your terminal, the part after computername@username, it has the path to the folder you are in. if the path is like `~` then you are in home. that is not the right folder. you need to be in the folder with the driver. so `cd` to that folder. re-read my instructions. or just open up the terminal in that folder with right click. you can check that you are in the right folder by typing `pwd` and `ls`. `pwd` gives you the folder location and `ls` it's contents.

Comment: actually i did get to the right folder  see for yourself  :   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z2MaLvuTPUC8y98gV6pLC6LL-cFGG-g2

Comment: how is that folder in any way shape or form the same folder as this : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o2QwkaKErzGZrzNmzmFaHg9FsmE0HrmD, in your screenshot you can clearly see there is no install.sh while there is in this drive link.

Comment: go inside that folder i sent and you will find more folder. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ok you have to go into "WiFi_Direct_User_Interface" your install.sh is there. for future reference the command `find -name "install.sh" -path . 2>/dev/null` allows you to find the file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AWuw9LFO8XW8rdHbiaadxLpb39JvdByl    error again during ./install.sh command saying command not found. And another information that could be important is that in the document folder there is a guide naming Quick_Start_Guide_for_Driver_Compilation_and_Installation of which I cannot follow it properly and gives error.

Comment: ok try editing install.sh and adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top. btw are you really really sure they meant for this driver to be installed for a x86 system (full computer in 64bit) rather than on an ARM architecture (android, raspberry, ect...)?

Comment: I am sure but did you see the document folders installation guide? I am confused in that part and might probably be the solution but for me its coomplicated. someone who is used to such might be able to figure it out

Comment: yeah the installation guide says run the install.sh file. you're missing the `#!/bin/bash` part at the top of that file but otherwise it should work.

Comment: I did and got no response and it turned out the install.sh in the first folder should do it and but it shows error at the time of doing it so I decided to create a new post on the specific error.

Comment: ok good idea. I'll help you out there if need be.

Comment: This is the link to the new question I hope you will check it.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132993/getting-error-in-compiling-install-sh-of-a-wireless-driver

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the post which actually worked its really awesome just in case if anyone needed it  :[Getting error in compiling install.sh of a wireless driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132993/getting-error-in-compiling-install-sh-of-a-wireless-driver/1133004?noredirect=1#comment1877659_1133004)