# Getting error in compiling install.sh of a wireless driver

Tags: drivers, compiling, make

I am trying to install a wireless driver that is provided with the adapter. but running

> sudo bash install.sh

I am getting the error. According to the readme file this should be the install script basically but it shows errors during the process. so the output from the commands and the errors are:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:325: recipe for target '/home/the_blank/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/the_blank/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/the_blank/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/the_blank/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic'
Makefile:504: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
```

And the link to the wireless driver is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o2QwkaKErzGZrzNmzmFaHg9FsmE0HrmD  If anybody knows what the problem is and how to solve it please do tell.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that a circa-2012 driver suite will ever build on any recent Ubuntu version as you've seen. Let's find a better way. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 the result is: 0bda:f179 Realtek Semicondictor Corp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please get a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or any means possible. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
cd rtl8188fu
sudo dpkg -i rtl*.deb
```

The process *dpkg* will take a few moments, please be patient. Next, do:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8188fu
```

Your wireless should be working.

Comment: can I install the zip clone of git offline by downloading the zip clone from the link?

Comment: Assuming that you have the necessary prerequisites installed, you can certainly do so. Are you unable to temporarily get an internet connection on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: No I have temporary internet connection.

Comment: Then simply follow each step as I gave it. It works. I already tried it on my 4.18.0-17 installation.

Comment: Thanks a million brother it really super awesomely worked. This is probably my best moment. awesome. Thanks again. And I was able to install it with the zip clone too.

Comment: you are a true saviour. Thank God for people like you _/\_