# trouble installing drivers for WiFi dongle (Compile make driver error: 1)

Tags: wireless

I'm currently trying to get a WiFi dongle to work with Ubuntu. It works fine with a previous installation of Windows 10, so the hardware shouldn't be an issue.
When running the install.sh file, I kept getting an error message reading:

Compile make driver error: 1

So after a bit of searching I found this thread
[Getting error in compiling install.sh of a wireless driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132993/getting-error-in-compiling-install-sh-of-a-wireless-driver)

that seemed to have similar trouble. (error: 2 though)
When trying the solution there, I got a "repository not found" error.

Edit:
lsusb returns
ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

This is the German Amazon where I gt the dongle: https://smile.amazon.de/gp/product/B07SZ7YVK9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3

The driver I'm trying to get to run is from a download link provided in a .pdf on the disk that came with the dongle. There are drivers on there too, but after they didn't work I figured the download might have a newer version that would. The downloadlink is shortened though, so I can't paste it in here. I'm not sure about the legality of reuploading it elsewhere.

Comment: Which wifi dongle? With the device inserted, please run: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to show the result. Where did you get the driver you are trying to compile? May we have a link? What Ubuntu version are you running? `lsb_release -d`

Comment: I added the information.

Comment: Please try the driver here: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959 Post back if you need a step-by-step.

Comment: I would have just gone ahead with the commands from the linked solution with your github link instead of the one provided there, and the appropriate other variables. Is that the way to go? Thx btw already for the help.

Comment: Please see my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959.git
cd rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Nevermind my comment just then, must have made a typo. It works like a charm. Thank you very much for the speedy help!